# How do I select entire column on selecting row cell in NatTable?

Tags: eclipse, nattable

We have a NatTable with no header and I treated the 1st row as a Header,
- Register CELL_PAINTER to change the visualization to look this row similar to header.

- Also registered the CustomCommandHandler which implements ILayerCommandHandler to prevent cell/row selection for the 1st row.

```java
   selectionLayer.registerCommandHandler(new CustomCommandHandler());
```

- Cell selection is working fine for other cells.

```java
  public boolean doCommand(final ILayer layer, final ILayerCommand command)
          {
            if (command instanceof ViewportSelectRowCommand)
            {
               return ((ViewportSelectRowCommand) command).getRowPosition() <= 1;
            }
            else if (command instanceof SelectCellCommand)
            {
              return ((SelectCellCommand) command).getRowPosition() <= 1
            }
            return false;
          }
```

Now how can I select the entire column on selecting cells on 1st row. So that it should not affect the cell selection for other row cells.

Clicking any cells on 1st row should select entire column.

Clicking any cells on other rows should select the same cell. (currently this is happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not quite sure what sense it makes to only have a body that is configured in a complicated way to look and behave like it has headers without really having headers (IMHO this does not make any sense), you need to register a custom handler that checks for the column position and transform the `SelectCellCommand` into a `SelectColumnCommand`.

```
this.selectionLayer.registerCommandHandler(new SelectCellCommandHandler(this.selectionLayer) {

    @Override
    public boolean doCommand(ILayer targetLayer, SelectCellCommand command) {
        if (command.convertToTargetLayer(targetLayer)
                && command.getColumnPosition() == 0) {
            return targetLayer.doCommand(
                    new SelectColumnCommand(
                            targetLayer,
                            command.getColumnPosition(),
                            command.getRowPosition(),
                            command.isShiftMask(),
                            command.isControlMask()));
        }
        return super.doCommand(targetLayer, command);
    }
});
```

But I expect there will be more issues on the way as the immitated headers do not behave like real headers also in other scenarios. You could also try to override `getRegionLabelsByXY(int, int)` but I am not sure if this would work or cause more problems.